# Weird flashing and flickering is showing. Can't even login in my kde debian 12

Tags: kde, login

I booted my laptop for the first time today. Everything goes smooth but when it gets to the login screen it displays weird flickering. Cannot login. Cannot open tty. Is there anything I can do?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.